# Xamarin forms WebView not loading for specific url

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi im using Xamarin forms webview and i had a specific url which is developed by my company when ever im loading the url the webview is returning empty screen can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you check the weburl is working fine by testing somewhere else, once its fine then post your code

Comment: yeah i took the same url and tested in chrome it is working fine.

Comment: And did you try another URL in your WebView? Like Google?

Comment: ya only one url is not showing up actually the page is heavy and more heavy ui in url

Comment: Please edit your post with the xaml/c# code from webview implementation.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message in a log?

Comment: Can you share the specific url or a test url that can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the URLs must be fully formed with the protocol specified (i.e. it must have "http://" or "https://" prepended to it).

```
var browser = new WebView
{
  Source = "http://xamarin.com"
};
```

Check your webview layout. Maybe is not have a good position in xaml.

For ios check NSAppTransportSecurity if the url is not https.

If you want open the browser tab inside your app check this 
https://askxammy.com/customizing-browser-appearance-in-xamarin-forms/